# Microsoft Bot Framework - Can't send a message and end dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, bots, botframework

I'm getting started to using MS's Bot Frameword, and I'm trying to build a simple bot.

The problem is that, if I send a message in a Dialog, I cannot end that dialog.

Here goes my code:

Entry point file of my bot

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
require('dotenv').load();
var fs = require('fs');

//Project modules
var consts = require('./modules/consts');
var u = require('./modules/utils');
var ds = require('./modules/dialogs');

if (process.env.config == consts.PRODENV) {
    u.dlog('Production environment; loading HTTPS');
    var server = restify.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.keyPath || './ssh/key'),
        certificate: fs.readFileSync(process.env.certPath || './ssh/cert')
    });
} else {
    u.dlog('Development environment; loading HTTP');
    var server = restify.createServer();
}

/*Definindo variáveis*/
//Lista de comandos
var commands = {
    evento: {
        pattern: 'evento',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('evento')
    },
    eventos: {
        pattern: 'eventos',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('eventos')
    },
    convidados: {
        pattern: 'convidados',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('convidados')
    },
    cancelar: {
        pattern: 'cancelar',
        action: builder.DialogAction.endDialog()
    }
}

//Objeto de bot principal
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot();
//Roteador de comandos
var cm = new builder.CommandDialog();

//Adicionando comandos
for (command in commands) {
    cm.matches("/?%s(.*)".replace('%s', commands[command].pattern), commands[command].action);
}

//Diálogo inicial
cm.onDefault(function(session) {
    session.send('Hey there!');
});

//Rota padrão
bot.add('/', cm);

//Adicionando diálogos
for (dialog in ds) {
    bot.add(dialog, ds[dialog].flow);
}

//Inicializando servidor
if (process.env.config == consts.PRODENV) {
    server.use(bot.verifyBotFramework({ appId: 'events-organizer-bot', appSecret: process.env.appSecret }));
}
server.post(process.env.uri || '/', bot.listen());
server.listen(process.env.port || 8080, function() {
    u.dif(function() {
        console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
    })
})
```

dialogs.js

```
module.exports = {
    "evento": {
        flow: function(session) {
            session.send('*evento*: implementando');
            session.endDialog();
        }
    },
    "eventos": {
        flow: function(session) {
            session.send('*eventos*: implementando');
            session.endDialog();
        }
    },
    "convidados": {
        flow: function(session) {
            session.send('*convidados*: implementando');
            session.endDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I get from that code:

```
Session Error: builder is not defined
```

I know I could send the message without starting the dialog, but these dialogs are gonna get more complex (of course). What if I want to confirm a information the user sent to the dialog and then end it?

----------------------------- Edit 1 -----------------------------

I reran my code after the update, but I'm still getting an exception.

Here goes the code:

Entry point:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
require('dotenv').load();
var fs = require('fs');

//Project modules
var consts = require('./modules/consts');
var u = require('./modules/utils');
var ds = require('./modules/dialogs');

if (process.env.config == consts.PRODENV) {
    u.dlog('Production environment; loading HTTPS');
    var server = restify.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.keyPath || './ssh/key'),
        certificate: fs.readFileSync(process.env.certPath || './ssh/cert')
    });
} else {
    u.dlog('Development environment; loading HTTP');
    var server = restify.createServer();
}

/*Definindo variáveis*/
//Lista de comandos
var commands = {
    evento: {
        pattern: 'evento',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('evento')
    },
    eventos: {
        pattern: 'eventos',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('eventos')
    },
    convidados: {
        pattern: 'convidados',
        action: builder.DialogAction.beginDialog('convidados')
    },
    cancelar: {
        pattern: 'cancelar',
        action: builder.DialogAction.endDialog()
    }
}

//Objeto de bot principal
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot();
//Roteador de comandos
var cm = new builder.CommandDialog();

//Adicionando comandos
for (command in commands) {
    cm.matches("/?%s(.*)".replace('%s', commands[command].pattern), commands[command].action);
}

//Diálogo inicial
cm.onDefault(function(session) {
    session.send('Hey there!');
});

//Rota padrão
bot.add('/', cm);

//Adicionando diálogos
for (dialog in ds) {
    bot.add(dialog, ds[dialog].flow);
}

//Inicializando servidor
if (process.env.config == consts.PRODENV) {
    server.use(bot.verifyBotFramework({ appId: 'events-organizer-bot', appSecret: process.env.appSecret }));
}
server.post(process.env.uri || '/', bot.listen());
server.listen(process.env.port || 8080, function() {
    u.dif(function() {
        console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
    })
})
```

dialogs.js

```
module.exports = {
    "evento": {
        flow: function(session) {
            //session.send('*evento*: implementando');
            session.endDialog('*evento*: implementando');
        }
    },
    "eventos": {
        flow: function(session) {
            //session.send('*eventos*: implementando');
            session.endDialog('*eventos*: implementando');
        }
    },
    "convidados": {
        flow: function(session) {
            //session.send('*convidados*: implementando');
            session.endDialog('*convidados*: implementando');
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking the default dialog wokrs fine, but invoking any of the other dialogs throws a `Session Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded` excpetion on my face.

Nothing wrong hapens if I don't pass any parameters to the enDialog method, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay... I don't know why you're getting that particular exception but there is an issue right now related to sending a message and then not being able to end the dialog in same call.  I have a fix/improvement that lets you pass a message as part of the call to endDialog(). Let me try to roll out a 0.7.0 update today that addresses this.

Comment: Just published v0.7.0 that adds this feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, calling endDialog witha string didn't work.

I've editted my question to include both the new code and the new exception